# Displaying messge when pausing a game in java

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent

I have [this game](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5gRlPuet22mTTcwOWZqMDlXVEU/edit?usp=sharing) developed in Java.

I have all functionality like pausing,resuming. But my problem now is to display a message which says " GAME PAUSED " in the middle of the `JFrame` when pausing the game. I tried to implement the `JLabel ImageIcon` but was unsuccessful. Please can someone provide some kind of help. Thanks in Advance.

```
public class NewClass extends JFrame implements KeyListener{

boolean for_pause;


 private DrawCanvas canvas;
 //variable declaration-end 
  public NewClass()  {
    //initializing the frame section
   canvas = new DrawCanvas();
  canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT));
  this.setContentPane(canvas);
  this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  this.pack();
  setLocationRelativeTo(null);
  this.setTitle("Bouncing Ball");
  this.setVisible(true);
    //this.setResizable(false);

 addKeyListener(this);
 draw_rect();

}

 ActionListener action = new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
       update();
       repaint();
    }
};
Timer t = new Timer(8,action);

public void update()
{
     x += xSpeed;
  y += ySpeed;
  if (x > CANVAS_WIDTH - size || x < 0)
  {
     xSpeed = -xSpeed;
  }
  if (y > CANVAS_HEIGHT - 80 || y < 0)
  {
     ySpeed = -ySpeed;
 }
}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ke) {
    //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {
    int keycode = ke.getKeyCode();
       if(keycode == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
       {
            if(xx == 5)
            {
                xx = 5;
            }
            else{ 
            xx = xx-15;
            }

       }
       if(keycode == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
       {

      if(xx == 515)
            {
                xx = 515;
            }
            else{ 
            xx = xx+15;
            }

       }

       if(keycode == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE)
       {
             if(for_pause == false)
             {
                 t.start();
                 for_pause = true;
             }


         }
       if(keycode == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE)
       {
             if(for_pause == false)
             {
                t.stop();
                for_pause = true;
             }  
             else
             {

                 t.start();
                 for_pause = false;
             }
         }
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke) {
    //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
}


 class DrawCanvas extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
     public DrawCanvas()
  {
      setBackground(Color.white);

     setLayout(null);
  }
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
     super.paintComponent(g);  // paint parent's background
     Graphics2D d = (Graphics2D)g;

     for(RoundRectangle2D r : s1){
        d.setPaint(gp1);
        d.setStroke(color);
        d.fill(r);
      }
     for(RoundRectangle2D r : s2){
        d.setPaint(gp2);
        d.setStroke(color);
        d.fill(r);
      }
     for(RoundRectangle2D r : s3){
        d.setPaint(gp3);
        d.setStroke(color);
        d.fill(r);
      }
     Board = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(xx,yy,120,10,20,20);
    //getting the center x and center y of the board--start 
    int Board_xm = (int)  Board.getCenterX();
    int Board_ym = (int) Board.getCenterY();
    Board_xm =Board_xm-15;
    Board_ym =Board_ym-25;

    Ball = new Ellipse2D.Double(x,y,size,size);

    d.setColor(Color.yellow);
    d.fill(Ball);
    d.draw(Board);


    collide_Bricks(); //function not included here
    collide_Board();//function not included here

 }

     }
```

Comment: how about just `if (paused) drawString()`?

Comment: The problem is that the game pauses when the user presses the `ESC` key. The `JFrame` and `JPanel` are in two different classes so I am not able to access the Object of the `Graphics` class,which should be used for drawing the String.

Comment: So what about a simple trigger solution? pass the reference which contains the graphic object to the event listener class, the event listener will simply trigger the target object to draw the pause string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [Glass Pane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html) to display a message of a component.

Comment: It will be nice of you if you can give me a example. Really confusing to read and understand that.